# any good software html verifier

Tags: html, css

How can I verify a html file is well formed? I want to find the problems such as lack of closing `</div>` vice versa.

Comment: Submit it to : http://validator.w3.org/ ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called [validation](http://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I actually use a bookmarklet for this purpose, tweaked to my liking:

```
javascript:window.open('http://validator.w3.org/check?uri='+escape(window.location)+'&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0&ss=1');void%200
```

I have this saved as a bookmark and visible on my bookmark bar.  It validates the code of the page I am looking at, but opens it in a new tab/window.  Very handy.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to do it once in a while, like in your browser?  Here's a fantastic plug-in for Firefox called HTML Validator. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/249/

The heavy-lifting of HTML Validator is done by Tidy, a C library, which is at http://tidy.sf.net.

One of the problems of Tidy is that they do not make releases.  Their installation instructions are "Get the latest from the CVS repo."  That's a problem for some of us, so I forked tidy into the tidyp project.  http://tidyp.com/

If you're using Perl and want a wrapper around tidyp to make it easier for your Perl programs to do validation, use HTML::Tidy.  http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Tidy/

Before I created HTML::Tidy, I wrote my own structural validator in pure Perl called HTML::Lint, which is at http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Lint/

All of this is from HTML 4 only.  If you're looking to validate XHTML and HTML 5, I have no suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The best validator so far is - in my experience - [Total Validator](http://www.totalvalidator.com/validator/ValidatorForm) (there's a [standalone version](http://www.totalvalidator.com/tool/index.html) as well). It's more accurate than [W3C's validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 0):

i use the "web developer toolbar" on firefox which redirects to http://validator.w3.org. It has a nice menu with options to validate css, html (both local and remote) and rss feeds.

Also it has other features unrelated to html validation.